# PGI compiling with -multicore

Tags: compilation, multicore, openmpi, pgi

I am compiling my code using PGI compiler with openmpi with `-multicore` flag and I get this error.

```
undefined reference to `**__pgi_uacc_cuda_stream**'
undefined reference to `**__pgi_uacc_cuda_initdinfoflags**'
undefined reference to `**__pgi_uacc_cuda_release_buffer**'
undefined reference to **'__pgi_uacc_cuda_argmem'**
```

I have removed all the async flags from my code

```
//#pragma acc update device( ptr[0 : end] ) async( 3 )
```

Comment: Can you please share a snippet of your code ?

Comment: please post your command line and the full error message - it should indicates where the undefined reference is coming from (object ? library ?)

Comment: Which OpenMPI are you using?  Did you build it yourself or are you using the one PGI supplies?  If you built it yourself what compiler flags did you using?  Could the MPI driver be implicitly adding the PGI NVIDIA GPU libraries such as libaccn.so?

Comment: I am using the PGI compiler built with OpenMPI/2.0.2 with -multicore flag.